# How to make a bot to message only certain people

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot

I developed a welcome bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework. I want to add it to Teams. In teams I want the bot to send welcome messages to only certain members belonging to a particular team or group. Please provide me advice or steps how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send a welcome message to a specific user if that user first contacted your bot. This is done purposefully to minimize the possibility of spam bots being created. Once a user has contacted your bot you can capture the user's Id and, coupled with the conversationId, you can send future (proactive) messages.

Comment: can u write a small botframework node js program in which i get the users conversation id during the first interaction and send them a good morning msg everyday!   please!